# Hash mixed value type comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to compare an Variable to a value within a hash, but the hash can be queried using both `Numeric` and `String` arguments.

```
ED_CONTRIBUTIONS = {
  1 => {
    db_code: 1,
    name: 'Provision of housing and transport',
    abbreviation: 'Provisions',
    group: 'Social development contributions'
  }
}
```

I use a method like this to do the comparison:

```
def find_item(field, value)
  value.downcase if value.is_a? String
  applicable_items.find { |k,v| v[field] == value}.andand.last || {}
end
```

but sometimes the `v[filed]` is the `db_code` and as a result a digit. how can i make it so that if `v[field]` is a string that it be downcased? or rather how does one check the state of the value of a hash in such an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it's a string like this `v[field].kind_of? String`, and downcase it if it is.
Or you can just `v[field].to_s.downcase` it without checking the variable type.

Comment: nice i dont know why i didnt think about just comparing a converted string. man that was a blond moment

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse it to a `String`:

`value.to_s.downcase`

and then you don't need to investigate if the `value` is a `String`

Comment: yeah i am going to go out now and punch myself its such a simple solution